# Direct Read from Blob using Generic parser

Tags: c#, azure, api, blob

I have a csv file of 1.7 GB Size which is located in Azure blobstorage. I need to find a method to read and store the data in memory using c# .net which should be fast.

I am able to download and read the csv file using generic parser .

```
var filepath = "D:../Sample_Data.csv";
using (GenericParserAdapter parser = new GenericParserAdapter(filepath))
{
dtResult = parser.GetDataTable();               
}
```

but when I have tried with **blobpathUri** I got exception

```
**System.ArgumentException: 'File, https://Sample.blob.core.windows.net/containername/Sample_Data.csv, does not exist.**
Parameter name: strFileName'
```

Is it possible to direclty reading from blob using Generic parser ? or anyone can suggest a **better method to read large file direcltly from blob** in which result should come fastly

Comment: any reason behind using generic parser ? have you tried filestream ? read as bytes and then process the way you need.

Comment: Thanks Aravind.  using (var sourceStream = wc.OpenRead(blockBlob1.Uri))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        csvstringpart = reader.ReadLine();
                        csvstring = csvstring + csvstringpart;
                    }
                }
            }  I have tried stream .but performance is very slow

Comment: Is your last comment code about concatenation in a tight while loop? Because yes can be an issue.  for the general "Performance is really slow" there is not enought informationz , Do you have a mre, or any numbers, stopwatches?   information. Note that Loading 1.7Go speed is limited by the reading speed.

Comment: My bast advice is to use something like CsvHelper and a `StreamReader`, with `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`  in app.config

Comment: Thanks Drag and Drop .I have tried by avoiding concatenation in while loop also .But its really slow .Have found CsvHelper .Bt I have found like we should create model for datacolumns.Is there any methods to use the same without creating model since there is 220 unknown columns.

Comment: Any suggestion should be appreciated .Please try to answer by giving code example.

Comment: Hi ,Anyonecan suggest which approach should be faster or better ,For same File having 1.7 GB Reading from Azure Blob,Reading from Azure Datalake ,Reading from Azure sql?